# Reusing types across multiple services and .net versions

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I have Services (Service1, Service2, ...) all which reference a Common.dll all of which are in **.Net 4.0**, and I am having trouble reusing the types in the consumer of the service.

---

Common.dll has

```
Identifier {
    int Id;
    string Type;
}
```

Each Service implements

```
byte[] Get(Common.Identifier);
string Test();
```

---

The consumer of the service (**.Net3.5**) generates code in reference.cs

```
class Service1 {
    byte[] Get(Service1.Identifier);
    string Test();  
}

class Service2 {
    byte[] Get(Service2.Identifier);
    string Test();  
}
```

---

I tied them together by creating an Interface
Adding the interface to partial classes, but can only get it to work for the Test() call

```
public interface IService {
    //byte[] Get(Service2.Identifier);
    string Test();  
}

public partial class Service1 : IService;
public partial class Service2 : IService;
```

---

This way I can use the services interchangably.
I plan on creating many more to use as basically plugins to integrate to different systems

```
IService GetService(string provider) {
    switch (provider) {
        case "Service1":
            return (IService)new Service1();

        case "Service2":
            return (IService)new Service2();
    }
}

GetService.Test() //works perfectly.
```

---

My problem is how do I define, decorate "Identifier" in such a way that will allow me to use the Get(?? Identifier) without writing a bunch of code.

The only way I can think of right now is to create an interface IIdentifier, and then add to the partial classes

```
public partial class Service1 : IService {
    byte[] Get(IIdentifier id) {
        return this.Get(new Service1.Identifier() { Id = id.Id, Type = id.Type});
}
```

but there are a lot of calls and I don't want to have to wrap them all. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, thanks for any help that can be provided.

Comment: "Each Service implements `byte[] Get(Identifier);`" but code show does something different - `byte[] Get(Service1.Identifier);`. Could you please clarify if the questions is "why I'm not using `Identifier` in `Get` methods" or "how to allow duck typing of `Identifier` class to match other types with the same properties" or something else... Re-read [MCVE] guidance on posting code as what provided in the post so far does not align between what post says and what code shows.

Comment: In the services themselves they implement byte[] Get(Common.Identifier), in the consumer of the services the reference code that is generated is byte[] Get(Service1.Identifier) which is the cause of problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov After a bit of reaserch it looks like I am looking for "how to allow duck typing of Identifier class to match other types with the same properties" It looks like it's for .net4.0, where my code consuming the services is .net3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was approaching this from the wrong side, and the way I was trying to do it wouldn't work as Alexei pointed out.

I managed to get everything to work and reuse the classes in the common.dll by compiling it for .net 3.5 instead of 4.0.

.Net 4.0 is backwards compatible with 3.5 so I was able to reference the 3.5 common.dll from my services which allowed my 3.5 code to reference common.dll and thus reuse the types.